# Convergence of beta function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Show that $$B(p, q) = \int_0^1 x^{p-1} (1-x)^{q-1} dx $$ converges for $p,q > 0$

I am not too sure how to do this, so any hints and solutions would be appreciated.

First of all, is it true to say that we have convergence for $p,q \geq  1$ since the integrand is continuous?

Now we just have to check for $p, q<1$.

I have tried to partition the integral, as we have discontinuous at $0$ if $p<1$ and at $1$ if $q<1$.

So I have done something that has been done in previous problems, to write $$B(p,q) = \int_0^{0.5} x^{p-1} (1-x)^{q-1} dx + \int_{0.5}^1 x^{p-1} (1-x)^{q-1} dx$$ but then I am not too sure what to do from here...

Comment: If $0 < x \leq .5$ then $(1-x)^{q-1}$ is bounded between $1$ and $.5^{q-1}$ so you can ignore it when considering convergence.

Comment: Also note: the negation of $p,q \geq 1$ is not $p,q < 1$.

Comment: @JairTaylor What is the negation then?

Comment: @PhysicsMathLove Think about it: if $p = 3$ and $q = .5$ then $p,q \geq 1$ is not true and $p,q < 1$ is also not true....

Comment: Sorry I meant $p$ and $q$ $\geq$ 1, and then considering $p$ or $q$ less than $1$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the negation of "$p \geq 1$ and $q \geq 1$" is "$p < 1$ or $q < 1$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1/2}x^{p-1}(1-x)^{q-1}dx,
\end{align*}
the term $(1-x)^{q-1}$ is good on $[0,1/2]$, there is no denominator problem here, and $(1-x)^{q-1}\leq C$ for $x\in[0,1/2]$, $C>0$ is some constant.

So
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1/2}x^{p-1}(1-x)^{q-1}dx\leq C\int_{0}^{1/2}x^{p-1}dx=\dfrac{C}{p}x^{p}\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=1/2}<\infty,
\end{align*}
for $0<p<1$.